# Flask Classful no me funciona con rutas

Tags: python-3.x, flask, server

Disculpen, estoy aprendiendo Flask y tengo una duda. He estado analizando, y no me cuadra lo que mostrare ahora. Necesito usar **Flask basado en POO**, encontre `Flask Classful` y su documentacion  [aquí](http://flask-classful.teracy.org/)

Pero no entiendo este código de ejemplo:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView

# we'll make a list to hold some quotes for our app
quotes = [
    "A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man! ~ Jebediah Springfield",
    "If there is a way to do it better... find it. ~ Thomas Edison",
    "No one knows what he can do till he tries. ~ Publilius Syrus"
]

app = Flask(__name__)

class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        return "<br>".join(quotes)

QuotesView.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

La página dice que para acceder hagamos uso de esta url:

```
 - http://localhost:5000/quotes/
```

Mi pregunta es ¿De dónde sale la ruta `/quotes/`? no lo entiendo.

Estoy intentando hacer esto con un proyecto, y cuando pongo una ruta me dice "error404".

Lo que no entiendo es como este código tiene la ruta quotes, si en ningún sitio veo que se halla definido.

Entonces también probé el código de la documentación y tampoco me funciona.

Creo que la web no es un sitio confiable y que esta mal o hay algo que no veo, si no es una pagina confiable, Entonces por favor ¿Me podrían dar una web confiable donde aprender a manejar Flask con POO? (documentacion completa porfavor). Y disculpen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta librería proviene de otra librería llamamda **Flask-Classy**. **Flask_Classy se quedó sin actualizar hace unos 8 años aproximadamente**. Esta librería es un intento de mantener Flask-Classy actualizado a las versiones y paquetes de Python actualmente.

Parece que están teniendo varios problemas a la hora de hacer que la librería funcione correctamente, de hecho no es muy usada con Flask. **Este ejemplo que tu has probado en concreto no funciona.**

El problema no es del sitio web, el sitio web es la documentación oficial, es decir los que han creado y contribuido la librería, por lo que es el mejor sitio para aprender como funciona dicha librería. En resumen es un problema propio de desarrollo de la librería, por lo que no vas a encontrar otro sitio mejor.

Por otro lado **te recomiendo usar los paquetes más conocidos y usados de Flask**, esto te evitará problemas ya que son paquetes que tienen mayor soporte y una comunidad más amplia, por lo que será difícil que tengan errores.

No tiene mucho sentido usar clases para Flask, si ya lo tienes con su forma habitual, **los decoradores** y funciona la mar de bien. Si quieres aprender POO con Python hay multitud de clases, tutoriales, documentación, que te enseñarán como funciona independientemente de la librería que uses, Con Flask no creo que sea la adecuada, ya que es un paquete basado en decoradores.

Por último, una forma de usar las clases es creando modelos con bases de datos, con `flask-sqlalchemy` por ejemplo. Pero como te dije en el parrafo anterior Flask no es un módulo orientado a POO.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada! Si te ha servido la respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, darle un punto positivo (en futuras respuestas cuando tengas más reputación").

Comment: Ok, soy nuevo aquí, pero creo que lo hize. Confírmame.